# Different software (scipy, matlab) giving different p-values (KendallTau)

Tags: matlab, scipy, kendall-tau

I'm working on a software codebase transfer between Python (scipy) and Matlab, and am wondering if anyone has any insight as to why I'd be getting different p-values when calculating the p-value for Kendall's Tau on the same arbitrary 100 element random vectors.

[image]

I assume there's something different about the normality approximation, but is this documented anywhere as far as we can tell??  The tau value itself is identical, but I'd like to be able to document expected changes in output.

Comment: They look close enough that no one will care. You can look at the source code for scipy and see if it's doing what you expect. (I don't know enough about matlab to know if you can do that there).